# How to get C++ to interact with the menus of a windows program/ how to get C++ to fully control another program

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, automation, interaction

I am trying use C++ to automate the production of PDFs followed by transferring them into an Excel worksheet and formatting the information (Data Mining).

I am able to open/run the 3rd party program using C++ `CreateProcess()` or `System()`. 
But I am unable to interact with the menu of the program to import data and produce PDFs.

I have been stuck for 2 days (C++ novice) but I have done a lot of searching so I think it can be done.

**Three quick questions:**

1. Is C++ the best way to create an executable to accomplish this?
2. How would one get C++ (or a more recommended language) to talk to an opened program? (It is not a Microsoft program, it's an individually developed program). Once I get this I should be able to use C++ to talk to Excel and finish the job using a macro.
3. Out of curiosity, is there a way to accomplish all of this just by using an Excel macro? I know Excel can copy data from a PDF, but I am not sure if it can interact with another program to produce the PDFs.

Thanks a lot in advance. I really really really need your help.

Comment: There's an Excel API.

Comment: `It is not a microsoft program -- it's an individually developed program` If this is a well known program, it might help to disclose what it is (usually you would use automation)

Comment: Thats the thing, it isn't a well known program. It was one created for a specific group. Essentially I want to know the general way to go about setting up the interaction between C++ and any program. Because this is just a random one.

Comment: Chris: Does this Excel Api give an .exe file that would be able to run smoothly? What are the advantages in your eyes to using this API over a language like C++?

Comment: @Kz9: The general term is called [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There is no one way in C++, the different ways are OS-specific and depend on whether the program provides an interface to communicate with.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.  

I am working in windows, and what I get is that there are 2 ways: using the command line or communicating with the interface. How would I go about figuring which way to select? Essentially how can I tell if the program allows interface communication and or command line communication.  I'm a novice to C++, bear with me please.

Comment: You cannot accomplish what you are doing with the command line. Most applications provide documentation on how to do it, you will have to look at the documentation or consult the group that made it.

Comment: Common communication strategies between two executables are sockets, pipes, or shared files.  However, both sender and receiver need to be coded to use these.